# On/With- Which is the right preposition to use here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, sentence-meaning

A supervisor asks their employee "how are we doing **with** that news piece," here, it is obvious that the supervisor wants to know about the progress of the news piece. My question is if the supervisor said "how are we doing **on** that news piece," would that be grammatically incorrect? Would the sentence mean something else?

1. How are we doing **with** that news piece?
2. How are we doing **on** that news piece?

What's the difference in meaning between these sentences? Is there a difference at all? Are both grammatically correct?

Comment: It makes no difference which preposition you use in the cited context - where ***at*** and ***re*** are less common but still perfectly acceptable alternatives. There might be other one-word "drop-in" alternatives too, that wouldn't make any difference to the meaning. But there *would* be a difference if we replaced the preposition with different possible verb-based elements: 3: *How are we doing **proofreading** that news piece?* and 4: *How are we doing **typesetting** that news piece?* obviously mean different things.